# How to know which user is online?

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io

I want to know that if 2 users in a room are online or not. if both are online then I want to tell it to the room that the user is online but I can't find a way to know how to tell they are online.

I have a global array which stores the acc_id of all the socket.id and gets updated everytime the socketid changes, by this I can know the user has not open another tab as a new tab gives a new client.

```
io.of('/').in(room).clients(function(error, clients) {
    console.log(clients.length);
    clients.forEach(function(iiid){
    ds.some(function(el) {
       if (el.socket_id === iiid && el.acc_id !== decrypted && clients.length >= 2) {
       io.to(room).emit('isasdjfg__-dfko', {
             dfhdf: "Oui", //Yes in French 
             pfg: room
        });
      }
 });
});
});
```

This checks if the clients in the room have a acc_id that is not equal to the current user id means if there are 2 people in the room, but this doesn't works.

Comment: Please use standard English capitalization. The first-person nominative is not "i" but "I". You are asked to do this because your question and its answers are permanently published for reference. If they prove popular, then someone else will have to come back to clean up your style. Even if English is not your first language, one expects that you would know enough to capitalize "I".

Comment: And "Yes in French" is 'Oui', not 'Qui'... :-)

Comment: @MarcoS edited, now would anyone like to help me out in the question?

Comment: Sorry, don't know much about socket.io... :-( Just reviewing posts... :-)

Answer (score 1):

The below code contains a `users` `array` in the `server`. When a user connects it sends a `connect event with an id`. That `id` is stored in the `users array`. When the user `disconnects` the `id` is removed from the array.  So you can make a condition when the user id is in the array user is `online` else `offline`.

```
if(users.includes(id))
console.log('online')
```

For checking if 2 users with id1 and id2 respectively are online

```
if(users.includes(id1) && users.includes(id2))
console.log("both are online")
```

Server

```
var users = [];

io.on('connection', function(socket){
  socket.on('connect', function(data){
 users[socket.id] = data.id;
  });
  socket.on('disconnect', function(){
    users.splice(socket.id,1);
  });
});
```

Client

```
var socket = io();
 socket.emit('connect',{id:'id'});
```

Comment: check the array for both users. If they both are present means they both are online

Comment: how can i get data on disconnect event?

Comment: My bad, made an oopsie. I have made edits, respond for any further queries.

Comment: And btw, you can send data to the server *during* disconnect event too. But it's just before disconnect. Refer this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40816355/socket-io-send-disconnect-event-with-parameter/40817685

Comment: hey `current` is global, it can be overwritten, which means that if a user logins then another logins and the first one left, the last user is kicked out

Comment: that is on the client side btw

Comment: That's why i was saving the acc_id's with the socket.id's in objects

Comment: have a look now

Comment: on reload the user will disconnect and it will be removed from the user array, and on re-connection its socket id will change but the user id will remain the same, which we actually want to check online status. socket.id was for storage purpose, so even if it changes it won't matter coz all we want is the user id which we have anyway